# Where to implement customization of members' accessors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, get, set, accessor

I'm using EF4 and I was wondering where would one implement custom code in the generated classes' members accessors ?

I don't want to touch the code in EDMXFile.Designer.cs since anytime the model gets updated I'll lose my customizations.

Any easy ideas ? Maybe create another class with inheritance on these entities?

Thanks,

Comment: You can create a partial class for each entity class and place your custom logic there.

Comment: Should those partial classes inherit from the EF generated entities classes ?

Comment: The idea behind the partial classes is to split to logic of given class between two or more source files. In case of inheritance you do not have to create partial class to the EF ones.
Helpful information regarding partial classes can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I voted this comment up because it introduced me to partial classes which I did not know of, but still, this is not a solution I was looking for.

Indeed, EF generates partial classes, that can be extended in other .cs modules, but I cannot redefine properties and their accessors because the compiler will whine about the property already being defined somewhere else.

Remember, I do not want to touch the generated Designer.cs file.

Comment: Another way to customize your EF model is to use T4 templates. The following articles shows how to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx
http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2011/03/customize-entity-framework-code.html

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue because as soon as I go back into the EDMX designer and add a new table to it, the .cs under the .tt gets overwritten, just like the edmxfile.designer.cs when using "Code Generation Strategy"->"Default".